# MSI Get Installed Property Value C++

Tags: windows-installer

I have property MYPATH in my MSI setup and I am installing some components to this path. Now I want to get the path where is my component installed. I am using following code:

```
INSTALLUILEVEL pervousUILevel = MsiSetInternalUI(INSTALLUILEVEL_NONE, NULL);
MSIHANDLE handle = NULL;
MsiOpenProduct(productCode,&handle);
wchar_t myPath[2048];
DWORD dwBuffer = 2048;
MsiGetProductProperty(handle, L"MYPATH", myPath, &dwBuffer); 
MsiCloseHandle(handle);
MsiSetInternalUI(pervousUILevel, NULL);
```

But I am still getting the default value "C:\MyDefaultPath" instead of "C:\The Path I Specified During The Installation". What am I doing wrong? 
 
Thanks 

 
Edit: 
 
I found out that the code:

```
wchar_t myPath[4096];
DWORD isBuffer = 4096;
MsiGetComponentPath(productCode, L"{component-guid}", myPath, &isBuffer);
```

Also returns the default path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are reading the value directly from the MSI package. You need to get the property value during the installation process, using [MsiGetProperty API methodm with a custom action.](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/serial-number-validation-dll.html) The linked example is for a custom action that does serial validation, what interest you from there is just the way you define a custom action and how to get the value, the rest of the code you don't need

Comment: Hello Bogdan, thank you for your reply! Is there any way to get this property value after the installation process is done i.e. in standalone c++ console application? Another think that confuses me is that when I get MsiGetComponentPath for a component that is installed to INSTALLDIR the function gives me the INSTALLDIR that was chosen for the installation.

Comment: MsiGetProperty works only during an installation. To get the value after the installation is done, you need to first save it, usually in the registry, and read it from there. This why indeed MsiGetComponentPath seems to be what you need. It is possible that you set the value for MYPATH after the costing operations (CostInitialize - > CostFinalize) are completed, but I cannot say for sure, as I have not used that much MsiGetComponentPath, I mostly  write custom actions to be executed during the install process.

Comment: Ive sent MYPATH directly when executing the MSI. Thanks for clarifying that this is the bad way to go, I will read the property from registry or some config file.